# I'm facing some issues when deploying web in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, qr-code

I will redirect to my web application written with flutter with the links I will give to the users by creating manually (qr code), but the problem is that the address of this site that I deployed with firebase is as follows; https://web-app-30399.web.app I will give some of the users a link like this; https://web-report-45387.web.app?745763098258940780594 because the id after the question mark will be the id of a document in the firestore. when the user opens this site, I want the application to take the part of the application after "?" in this link and reach that document. I tried a little but I couldn't succeed. after deploying, I get the error in the picture.

```
Future<void> getLocationId() async {
    String? link = await getInitialLink();
    initialLink.value = link as String;
    initialLink.value = Uri.parse(initialLink.value).query;
    if (initialLink.value == "") {
      initialLink.value = "FJ9ISNeHjkbD5Uok5Eco";
    }
  }`

`Future<void> initializeAndGetLocationAndProjectDoc(String id) async {
    await getLocationId();
    await getLocationAndProjectDoc(initialLink.value);
  }`


`class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  FirstPage({super.key});
  final projectServiceController = Get.put(ProjectService());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('First page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: projectServiceController.initializeAndGetLocationAndProjectDoc(
              projectServiceController.initialLink.value),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Hata: ${snapshot.error}');
            } else {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                      '${projectServiceController.projectName.value}'),
                  Text(
                      '${projectServiceController.locationName.value}'),
                  
                ],
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I haven't tried much.

Comment: I don't see a picture in the code. Did you forgot to attach it?


Also: it's better to not show pictures of textual content, but instead show the actual content as text. That way it can be read by everyone (including crawlers) and is more likely to be found.

Comment: Don't forget that you have to grab the initial URL before you call `runApp` - otherwise it gets changed and it's too late to read it. In your `main()` grab the current HREF, save it in a variable, then call runApp